# Rotate group of duplicate bones in edit mode

Tags: bones

This is the  first time rigging anything in Blender. I'm attempting to rig a spider. I have created a set of 6 bones for one leg. Now I simply want to duplicate those bones and place and rotate them about 20 degrees over the next leg. I can duplicate the bones and translate them, but I can't figure out how to rotate them as a unit to align them with the next leg without destroying their relative alignment and positions to one another. I'm looking for a shortcut to rigging each leg. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out a solution. I duplicate the bones then separate them into a new armature. I can then rotate the the armature in object mode. I then combine the separate armatures back into one.

Comment: Find on yoitube some basic tutorial how to rotate and translate objects in blender. With no such skills you maybe finish the legs of your spider, but you couldn't make it dance.

Comment: While your answer works, it's a little cumbersome.  Try the "3D Cursor" pivot from the bar on top of or below the 3D viewport, place a cursor using the cursor tool or via shift-s snap menu, and then rotate your selection in edit mode.